# How can I reuse variable from super class method?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am creating a complete Box calculation program in Java. Actually the value of variable named `volume` should be 125 if width = 5, height = 5, depth = 5, but why the output display the value is 0 whatever any value for `width`, `height` and `depth`. I need help please....

Below is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Box obj1 = new Box();
        MatchBox obj2 = new MatchBox();

        System.out.print("Please Enter Width: ");
        obj1.width = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
        System.out.print("Please Enter Height: ");
        obj1.height = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
        System.out.print("Please Enter Depth: ");
        obj1.depth = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());

        obj1.getVolume();
        obj2.displayVolume();
    }
}

class Box {
    int width, height, depth, volume;

    void getVolume() {
        volume = width * height * depth;
    }
}

class MatchBox extends Box {
    void displayVolume() {
        System.out.println("The Volume of Box is: " + volume);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your are operating on the dimensions of `obj1` but then you are printing the volume of `obj2`!

Comment: you assign value to `obj1` but display from `obj2`

Comment: the instance `obj1` is not related to `obj2` (just having some common class/superclass) - there are totally different instances (real world example, if you change the tires of your car, it does not change of all vehicles you own)

Answer (score 2):

you create one instance of the class Box with the name obj1 and one instance of the class MatchBox with the name obj2. What this does is not quite what you want in this example!

Here is what your code should look like:

```
...
MatchBox matchBox = new MatchBox(); ' you only need to create this instance

System.out.print("Please Enter Width: ");
matchBox.width = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
System.out.print("Please Enter Height: ");
matchBox.height = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
System.out.print("Please Enter Depth: ");
matchBox.depth = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());

matchBox.getVolume();
matchBox.displayVolume();
...
```

Like this only one new instance of a MatchBox is created and because MatchBox is a subclass of Box it also automatically has all the attributes and properties that Box has.

Cobra_8